# Requesting regex pattern repetition fix for Sonar

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Seeking assistance in optimizing a regex pattern to satisfy Sonar:

[image]

Is there a way to reduce/refactor this?

Sample:

```
/api/v1
/api/v1/
/api/v1//
/api/v1///
/api/v23
/api/3
/api/2
/adad/adad/1
/api/2/asd/2
/a
/
```

Expected match:

```
/api/v1
/api/v1/
/api/v23
/api/3
/adad/adad/1
/api/2/asd/2
/a
/
```

Comment: This is fine as is. Ignore the Sonar warnings, they are 99% useless.

Comment: Note you do not need the alternation, if the string can be empty or just contain a single `/` char, use `"^(?:/[^/?&#\\s]+)*/?$"`

Comment: oh that's brilliant, thanks again!